# Recover a list of entities with related entities while omitting some fields using JPQL or criteria API

Tags: java, jpql, criteria-api

I have three entities: A, B, C

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor

@Entity
public class A {

    private long id;

    private String secret;

    @Builder.Default
    @Valid
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<B> bList = new LinkedList<>();

}

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor

@Entity
public class B {

    @JoinColumn
    private A a;

    private long id;

    private String secret;

    @Builder.Default
    @Valid
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "b", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<C> cList = new LinkedList<>();

}


@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor

@Entity
public class C {

    @JoinColumn
    private B b;

    private long id;

    private String secret;
}
```

I would like to recover the values from the DB **EXCEPT** the "secret" where the id of A belongs to a List of ids. **I do not want the secret of either A, B or C to be requested from the DB**. (in reality the data is much more complex, and the fields I don't want take too much time to be fetched from the database).

I've been trying to create such a query using JPQL or the Criteria API, but without success, I am unable to get even a list of B without the secrets.

For example in JPQL:

```
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery
                ("SELECT a  " +
                        "FROM A a where a.id in :aIds");
        query.setParameter("aIds", aIds);
```

This will work, but unfortunately it also requests the secret of A, B and C.

What I want instead would be something like (this code obviously does not work):

```
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery
                ("SELECT a.id, a.bList.id, a.bList.cList.id" +
                        "FROM A a where a.id in :aIds");
        query.setParameter("aIds", aIds);
```

I cannot change the entities (besides adding new constructors or methods) as they are used elsewhere and in other queries.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can create `dto` class with fields you need and populate it. The problem is that database query is able to return plain result only. Persistence provider can convert it to entities. As for `dto` you have to solve the problem yourself.

You can get `List<Object[]>` as query result

```
select a.id, b.id, c.id 
from A a join a.bList b join b.cList c 
where a.id in(:aIds)
```

Then you should convert query result to  `dto`